# Engine won’t start

Tags: chevrolet, ignition, starter, suburban, crank

My 2003 suburban won’t start, I lifted my steaming wheel up and my whole truck turned off and when putting the key in the ignition and trying to start the truck the starter doesn’t even click. My dash will only light up my battery light almost indicating that my battery is dead but the battery it’s self it’s a brand new perfect battery that has been tested I’ve also checked all fuses which are all working and testing 12 volts on each side. Please if someone has any ideas on what’s going on let me know

Answer (score 0):

When you have a problem like this DO NOT rule out anything.  Just because the battery is new doesn't mean that it's OK.  But my recommendation is:

1. Check the battery connections.  A loose or corroded connection at the battery can cause these symptoms.
2. Check the starter solenoid and its connections.
3. You said "I lifted my steaming wheel up and my whole truck turned off".  Perhaps there is a wiring fault in the ignition wiring or the switch.  Check it.
4. Check the starter motor.
5. Have the battery load tested.  It may be new but it may be defective.

Comment: I’ve narrowed it down to the wires that are shorting it out anyway I can send you a video and you can see and possibly give me some input?

Comment: https://youtu.be/htJ_tJdY5Qg This is my exact truck

Answer (score 0):

I would look closely at the wiring to the ignition switch, it may have damaged wires as the ignition switch moves with the steering column.

It may be the starting signal wire or the transponder wire that lost contact and is preventing the vehicle from being started.

While the battery may also be the issue, I find that somewhat unlikely as the truck was running as you say until you moved the steering wheel.